# Get attributes values from select2 selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I'm using the Select2 plugin from http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-latest.html what works fine but i'm having a problem to get the values from the options attributes.

I've got a select menu like this:

```
<select name="invoice_line[0][vat]" class="vat">
    <option value="20440" data-value="21.00" data-name="20440" selected="selected">21%</option>
    <option value="20441" data-value="6.00" data-name="20441">6%</option>
    <option value="20442" data-value="0.00" data-name="20442">0%</option>
</select>
```

How can I get the values of the attributes 'data-value', 'data-name' and 'value' of the selected option?

Answer (score 13):

```
obj = $("#dropdown").select2("data")
```

in `obj` variable i will get all the `data` of the `selected node`.

Comment: Not working, obj = undefined. im using tags btw.

Answer (score 6):

This was answered in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22261210/2407209)

> There is no direct method with select2, you can use a combinaison of select2 data and jQuery :
>
> $("#example").select2().find(":selected").data("id");
>
> First you get the select2 data then you find your selected option with jQuery and finally the data-attribute.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a combination of select2 data and jQuery :

```
$("#example").select2('data').element[0].attributes['data-name'].value
```

Comment: $("#example").select2('data')[0].element.attributes['data-name'].value
it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me. Idea is to use "change" function as follows

```
<select class="drop-down">
     <option value="0">A</option>
     <option value="1">B</option>
</select>

$('.drop-down').select2().on("change", function(e) {
    var obj = $(".drop-down").select2("data");
    console.log("change val=" + obj[0].id);  // 0 or 1 on change
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: can't access property 0, obj is undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
var return_option = $("#your-select-input-id").select2().find(":selected")[0];
```

above given statement will return select option and then put that return result as given below:

```
var name_of_attribute = $( return_option ).attr('name-of-attribute');
```

This will return the attribute value.

Comment: You sir, are my hero!
I simplified it a bit by doing var obj = $($("#your-select-input-id").select2().find(":selected")[0]); but either way works 100% :), I hate how they set this up.

Answer (score 0):

No idea about the pluggin, and without checking if the code works i imagine it would be something like this:

```
$('.vat li').each(function(){
     var me = $(this),
     mevalue = me.attr('value'),
     datavalue = me.data('value'),
     dataname = me.data('name');

     //do what you want with the data?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put select2 into tagging mode , it will help you. 
Or 
Try below similar code, it may work for you ...

```
$("$id").select2("val", option);
$("$id").attr("data-name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but I was struggling with this same problem. This is the solution that me and my good friend Thys finally got to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#e1").select2();

    $("#e1").change(function () {

        var theID = $("#e1").val();
        $('#staffNr').val(theID);
        $('#staffNr').val();
            //var theID = $(test).select2('data').id;
            var theSelection = $(test).select2('data').text;
            $('#selectedID').text(theID);
            $('#selectedText').text(theSelection);
    });

});
```

```
@Html.Hidden("fieldName","staffNr");
```

This worked in my MVC 4 view with the last line in my html form where it is correctly added to the model. Don't forget to up-vote if you use my answer please :) I haven't got much of a reputation...

Answer (score 0):

```
el = document.getElementsByName("invoice_line[0][vat]")
el.options[[el.selectedIndex]].attributes["data-id"].value
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you solved the issue. Here we dont use `select2()`, if we use `select2()` it will not work all other functions like `formatNoMatches, on-change....`

```
$("#example").find(":selected").data("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `params.data.element` object of the selected item holds the data you're looking for.

Where `.foo` is the select element I'm calling, and the data attribute within the options I want to access is `data-bar="some value"` The following works for me:

```
var $fooSelect = $('.foo');
$fooSelect.on(function (e) {
  console.log($(e.params.data.element).data('bar'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access to attributes looking in DOM structure:

```
<select id="select_name">
   <option value="20440" data-value="21.00">21%</option>
   <option value="20441" data-value="6.00">6%</option>
   <option value="20442" data-value="0.00">0%</option>
</select>

    $('#select_name option').each(function (index) {
        console.log($(this).attr("data-value"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

set an id for your select element and this would work

```
$('select#your-id').find('option[value="'+$('#your-id').val()+'"]').attr('data-attribute');
```

Answer (score 0):

You haveto do it with **on("change"...** because of this is a dynamicly generated option list.

```
$('.select_class').on("change",function(){
    var selected_value= $('.hakemler').val();
    var wanted= $('.select_class').find('option[value="'+selected_value+'"]').attr('data-foo');
    alert(selected_value+" "+wanted);
});
```