# Get custom data-attribute in select2 with <select>

Tags: html, jquery-select2, custom-data-attribute

Let's assume you have the following HTML5

```
<select id="example">
    <option value="AA" data-id="143">AA</option>
    <option value="BB" data-id="344">BB</option>
</select>

$("#example").select2();
```

How do I get the data-id from the selected option ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no direct method with select2, you can use a combination of select2 data and jQuery like following :

```
$("#example").select2().find(":selected").data("id");
```

First you get the select2 data then you find your selected option with jQuery and finally the data-attribute.

Comment: Actually i would say that 
$("#example").find(":selected").data("id");

Comment: @UgoRobain your solution works perfectly where the previous one does not work in same cases . in  my case I had `formatResult` and  `formatSelection` , only yours helped , thanks

Comment: this does not seem to work in select2 3.5 with IE Edge (at time of writing - Jan 2019)

Comment: `$("#example").select2().find(":selected").data("id");`
This will run reinitialization.
Better to use @UgoRobain method

Comment: In my case, After using this solution it hit dropdown again and because of this dropdown custom UI break ..Other wise this will working properly. Thanks

Answer (score 27):

Select2 v4 relies on `<select>` tags instead of hidden `<input>` tags so it's now easier to get the selected option or options: you just refer to the original `<select>`. This may have also been the case with Select2 v3 but I've only used Select2 v4.

```
$('#example option:selected').attr('data-id')
```

[jsfiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fnzhspLv/)

See also [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/185034)

**Edit:** I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30582675/185034) for general purpose data object access:

```
var d = $("#dropdown").select2("data");
```

`d` will be an array containing the selected item(s) as objects, so to access the `id` property of the first item:

```
var id = d[0].id;
```

Comment: For whatever reason, this was the only method that worked for me: `$('#example option:selected').attr('data-id')`

Comment: This was worked for me thanks..$('#example option:selected').data("attrName")

Answer (score 17):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#myselect').select2({
        templateResult: formatOutput
    });

});
function formatOutput (item) {
    var $state = $(item.element).data('id') + ' ' + item.text;
    return $state;
};
```

Comment: Could you explain why your answer works?  Just posting code is generally not that helpful

Comment: its on the plugin documentation.
you can format the template result using a function that recives the "item" as parameter, and using "item.element", returns the element itself, so u gan get any atribute from it.

Answer (score 8):

so simple, using jquery api [tested against select2 4.x version]

```
$('#select').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    let id = $(e.params.data.element).data('id');
});
```

Comment: The simplest and elegant solution when using `select2:select` event

Comment: Correct answer if you are using multiple option

Answer (score 7):

After hours of trying to solve this, I have manage to pull out the attribute. I am using 3.5.4

```
$("#select2").select2('data').element[0].attributes[1].nodeValue
```

HTML

```html
<select id="select2" name="course" class="form-control">
  <option></option>  
  <optgroup label="Alabama">  
    <option value="City 1" data-url="/alabama/city-1">City 1</option>  
    <option value="City 2" data-url="/alabama/city-2">City 2</option>  
  </optgroup>  
</select>
```

```js
$("#select2").select2('data').element[0].attributes[0].nodeValue --> Value Attribute
$("#select2").select2('data').element[0].attributes[1].nodeValue --> Data-URl Attribute
```

Comment: Be cautious about this, because if you change or add one more attribute you will break it

Comment: Thank you, this is the right solution for 4.x. The key was the ('data') part. In my case, it was: `$(<selector>).select2('data')[0]...`

Answer (score 4):

we can simply do this like:

```
$(this).find(":selected").data("id")
```

Answer (score 2):

My contribution on how to get value of data-attibute of selected option using Select2 event (3.5) (thx to [@loreto g's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32499164/1458189)):

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="foo" data-type="bar" data-options='baz'></option>
</select>

<script>
var myselect = $('#myselect').select2();

myselect.on('select2-selecting', function(sel){

    var seltype = sel.choice.element[0].attributes['data-type'].value,
        seloptions = sel.choice.element[0].attributes['data-options'].value;

});
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I use select2 to load all of my options dynamically (from an array), and this is what I have been able to use successfully:

```
$('#element').select2('data')[0].dataAttribute;
```

where the id of the select is 'element', and dataAttribute is the custom attribute for the option i'm trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Ad Per @Kalzem Example that works perfectly fine But you have to mention your attribute like this `data-attributeName` . You must mention `data` at first then mention your `attributes` name . Example : `<option value="AA" data-attributeName="143">AA</option>` and you will get the data with `$("#example").select2().find(":selected").data("attributeName");`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handle it. Not sure about opt-groups.

HTML

```
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
  <option value=""  data-url=""></option>   
    <option value="City 1" data-url="/alabama/city-1">City 1</option>  
    <option value="City 2" data-url="/alabama/city-2">City 2</option>   
</select>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#myselect").select2({
    width: '100%',
    templateSelection: function (data, container) {
        // Add custom attributes to the <option> tag for the selected option
        $(data.element).attr('data-url', data.dataset.url);
        return data.text;
    }
});

var url = $("#myselect").find(':selected').data('url');
```