# Select2 formatResult get attributes of option

Tags: html, jquery-select2

[Get custom data-attribute in select2 with <select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261209/get-custom-data-attribute-in-select2-with-select)

We need the same thing specified in the above link. But, how to get the attributes of option element in formatResult function?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following code :

```
  $select2.data('placeholder', 'please choose').html(_options).select2({
                    formatNoMatches: function (term) {
                        return 'There is no "' + term + '" item';
                    },
                    formatResult: function(term) {
                        return $(term.element).data('cnt');
                    },
                    allowClear: true
  });
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wicutoti/11/edit)

Comment: return $(term.element).data('cnt'); works perfectly!