# How to pass <option> attributes to select2?

Tags: jquery, html-select, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 4.0. I have a list of options, some of which are "deleted" and I want to signify which are which. My select element is like this:

```
<style>.deleted { color: red; }</style>

<select name="itemid" id="item-list" tabindex="1">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2" class="deleted">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

And it's initialised like this:

```
<script src="/static/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#item-list").select2({
        placeholder: 'Select item'
    });
});
</script>
```

However, on the resulting HTML code that select2 generates I don't see any way to reference that class. Also tried a `data-deleted` attribute on the option, with no luck.

The only thing I see that comes close is the [`templateResult`](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating) option, where I can check for `opt.element.className`. But I cannot see how to access the select2 option from there. Anyway that callback runs on every single search which is not at all what I want.

Is there some other way to style particular options in Select2?

UPDATE: as noted in the comments there is a `find()` function, but that only gets the original `<option>` elements, not the `<li>` elements that select2 generates. Here's what I tried:

```
var sel2 = $("#item-list").select2({
    placeholder: 'Select item'
});

sel2.find('.deleted').each(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: @isherwood what do you mean, what data?

Comment: The HTML is generated server-side, so the page is exactly like my code in the question.

Comment: In that case, it looks like you can get attributes using `find()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261209/get-custom-data-attribute-in-select2-with-select/22261210#22261210

Comment: I think you can use `find()` function for this

Comment: That only gets the original elements, see my update.

Comment: What version of Select2 are you trying to do this with?

Comment: @KevinBrown v4, as stated in the question :)

Comment: 4.0.0 or 4.0.1-rc.1? There was a change introduced in 4.0.1 that will make this possible.

Comment: 4.0.0 currently, but post your answer and I'll upgrade.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As of Select2 4.0.1 [(just released)](https://github.com/select2/select2/releases), you can transfer classes with the `templateResult` option. The first parameter is the data object being displayed, and the second argument is the container that it will be displayed in.

```js
$("select").select2({
  templateResult: function (data, container) {
    if (data.element) {
      $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
    }
    return data.text;
  }
});
```

```css
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.blue { background-color: blue }
.green { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.js"></script>

<select class="select2">
  <option value="AL" class="yellow">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK" class="blue">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ" class="green">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Any idea regarding it's previous version?

Answer (score 8):

If you also want to use the add the class to the selected items call the same function from `templateSelection`.

```
function select2CopyClasses(data, container) {
    if (data.element) {
        $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
    }
    return data.text;
}

$("select").select2({
    templateResult: select2CopyClasses,
    templateSelection: select2CopyClasses
});
```

Comment: That's the complete answer in my opinion

Comment: Yes, that's true

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="ddldevicetype" name="ddldevicetype" class="select2 form-control">
    <option value='' disabled selected>Please Select</option>
    <option value="1" data-ico="fa-light fa-desktop">desktop</option>
    <option value="2" data-ico="fa-light fa-laptop">laptop</option>
    <option value="3" data-ico="fa-light fa-tablet-button">tablet</option>
    <option value="4" data-ico="fa-light fa-mobile-button">mobile</option>
    <option value="5" data-ico="fa-light fa-print">printer</option>
    <option value="6" data-ico="fa-light fa-server">server</option>
</select>
```

```
$('#ddldevicetype').select2({
  templateResult: setdevicetype
});

function setdevicetype(devicetype) {

    if (!devicetype.id) {
        return devicetype.text;
    }       

    var $devicetype = $('<span style="color:green"><i class="' + $(devicetype.element).attr("data-ico") + '"></i> ' + devicetype.text + '</span>');

    return $devicetype;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want do this by default, every new select2 copy the class definition from option to select2-element. 
Include the code after loading select2.js

```
$.fn.select2.defaults.set("templateResult", function(item, li) {
  if (item && item.element && item.element.className.length) {
    $(li).addClass(item.element.className);
  }
  return item.text;
}
```

Comment: Please make a sample why this dosn't work. It works fine on some customer projects so what kind of error you get?