# How to keep source select's attributes (like CSS classes) in Select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I would like to have Select2 include all the CSS classes of the original source in its selection and results drop-down rendering.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33966565) uses the `templateResult` option and works for the results drop-down. It *seems* to work when I use the same code for `templateSelection` as suggested in the [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40300702), but there is a problem:

```js
function copyClassesToSelect2(data, container) {
    if (data.element) {
        $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
    }
    return data.text;
}

(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(function () {
        $("#my-select").select2({
            allowClear: true,
            minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
            templateResult: copyClassesToSelect2,
            templateSelection: copyClassesToSelect2
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.one {background: cyan}
.two {background: yellow}
.three {background: lightgreen}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="my-select" class="my-select" name="my-select" data-placeholder="--- Please select ---">
    <option value="">--- Please select ---</option>
    <option value="one" class="one">One</option>
    <option value="two" class="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three" class="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

When changing the selection, the rendered selected item keeps all the previously attached classes. Therefore, when selecting "one" or "two" **after** "three", they both stay green instead of their respective color. Also, when clearing the selection, the placeholder has the green background.

1. How would I need to modify the `templateSelection` callback to make the selected item only have the desired class?
2. Would the hardly documented  options `adaptContainerCssClass` and `adaptDropdownCssClass` be of any help here? What do they do?
3. Is there a better approach to make Select2 inherit all the original source attributes, for example `class="my-select"` from the original `<select>`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround:

```
function copyClassesToSelect2(data, container) {
    if (data.element) {
        $.each($(container).attr('class').split(' '), function(index, cssClass) {
            if(!cssClass.match("^select2-")) {
                $(container).removeClass(cssClass);
            }
        });

        $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
    }
    return data.text;
}
```