# jQuery Select2 - get style attribute from original option's select

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select class="select2">
    <option value="1" style="background-color: #ff0000;">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="2" style="background-color: #ffffff;">OPTION 2</option>
    ....
    <option value="144" style="background-color: #000000;">OPTION 144</option>
</select>
```

and finally, I use select2 on print this select list:

```
$('.select2')select2();
```

The problem is with style attribute - when I set this attribute into every option, jQuery script doesn't copy this attribute for `<li>` lists.

I know, I can set every `background-color` into `<style></style>` tags, but I have more options (~150) and I manage this attribute (background-color) on my site as live (when user change some options, then I change background-color), so I need solution which will be live-copy style attribute from original options list and when I reset select list (using `$('.select2').select2()`), bg color will be reset also.

How I can do it?

**@UPDATE**

I solved problem in that way:

```
function formatState(data, container)
    {
        if (data.element)
        {
            $(container).css('background-color', '#'+$(data.element).attr('data-style'));
        }
        return data.text;
    }

$('.select2').select2({templateResult: formatState});
```

and I replace options HTML code:

```
<option value="1" style="background-color: #ff0000;">OPTION 1</option>
```

for this:

```
<option value="1" data-style="ff0000">OPTION 1</option>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the first point, just as an option, you can define classes and use it like the jquery example below with replacing the `.data('style')` with `.data('class')` and `style="` with `class="`. Then you can write this HTML

```html
<!-- ... -->
<option value="1" data-class="option-white">OPTION 1</option>
<!-- ... -->
```

**SOLUTION**

Otherwise you can templating the dropdown with the `templateResult` option - you [find the docs here](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating).
Based on the example you shared I would solve it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function formatState(state) {
    if (!state.id) {
      return state.text;
    }

    return $(
      '<div style="' + $(state.element).data('style') + '"> ' + state.text + '</div>'
    );
  };

  $('.select2').select2({
    templateResult: formatState
  });
  
});
```

```css
.select2-results__option { padding: 0 !important; }
.select2-results__option div { padding: 6px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2">
    <option value="1" data-style="background-color: #ff0000;">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-style="background-color: #ffffff;">OPTION 2</option>
    <!-- .... -->
    <option value="144" data-style="background-color: #000000;">OPTION 144</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your solution is helpful but not exactly because it works and text of option has background that I set - it's good. But the problem is with background of full option (not only text but all place of option) - here is still white background. I need solution for set background of all place into every option. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: I solved my problem based on your example - `templateResult` was very helpful and this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926375/how-to-pass-option-attributes-to-select2
I edited my first post with solution. Thanks.

Comment: @PavloP Your solution is the pretty good. If you want to know another solution, there is a option with modifing the `CSS` of the container (see in my editet answer).

Comment: In my case, I can't use classes because user can set background color using colorpicker, so I can't create CSS classes with 100.000 color options (or more).