# Style With CSS a Single Select2 Option

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-select2

Our project is using Select2, and I'm struggling to style a single dropdown option.

```
<div class="mb-1">
        <select
            name="locations[]"
            class="form-control full-size"
            id="js-location-picker"
            data-is-select2
            data-placeholder="Locations"
            multiple
        >
           
            <option id="select-all-style" value="all">Select ALL Locations</option>
            <?php foreach ($locations as $locId => $location): ?>
                <option
                    value="<?= e($locId) ?>"
                    <?= in_array($locId, $selectedLocations) ? 'selected' : '' ?>
                >
                <?= e($location) ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

What I tried is using the style attribute inside the option tag and wrapping Select ALL Locations in a span and applying the style to span.

Also tried manipulating the element with JS, but to no avail.

```
$('#select-all-style').attr('color', 'red');
$("#select-all-style").css('color','red');
```

Comment: `Select2` creates a new DOM elements based on the source `<select>` element - so using `$('#select-all-style')` will only select the original source `<option>` which isn't used in the replacement content. You'll need to use Select2's own API.

Comment: Check out the following answer on Stackoverflow for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61610775/432074