# How to get custom data-attribute of select2 selected values

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have found similar question with solution here: 
[Get custom data-attribute in select2 with <select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261209/get-custom-data-attribute-in-select2-with-select)

I have placed custom data attribute with each option.

```
<option value="pen" data-price="2.5">Pen</option>
```

When I applied the accepted solution of that question,

```
var price = $(this).select2().find(':selected').data('price');
```

I get "Cannot read property 'current' of null".

[Here is my fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/z0qo84bh/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your price variable is iterable. You have to iterate all selected options.

Try this:

```
    $('.select-multiple').change(function () {
      var price = $(this).find(':selected');

      $.each(price, function(){
          console.log('Price: ', $(this).data("price"));
      });
    });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xy7cg5tv/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.select-multiple').on('select2:select',function (e) {
   var price = $(e.params.data.element).data('price');
   console.log(price);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lutqe3so/7/)

Comment: It's printing 2.5 only for every selected value: https://i.imgur.com/aZCxsCH.png