# Include a javascript variable into a ruby code in js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a select input where the user can pick a Company. Each company has an image url, I want that when the user click on a select option, the image of the company is added next to select input. Here I want to have the `data.id` to return it's value so that the url can be generated with the correct image.

In my view I have

```
<img class="my_img" src="">

<%= select("company", "company_id", Company.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { id: "select-company"})%>
```

In my js.erb file I have

```
$('#select-company').on('select2:select', function (e) { 
  var data = e.params.data;
  $(".my_img").attr("src", "<%= Company.find(#{data.id}).logo_url(:thumb) %>");
});
```

Comment: This example just won't work at all. The ERB interpolation happens on the server and it does not actually run javascript.  So you will just get a NoMethodError. What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish with this code? (and please don't say "include a javascript variable").

Comment: I'm trying to change an image on change of a select

Comment: Can you add an example of the view and user story? This sounds like you should  use data attributes to attach urls to elements in your view.

Comment: I've added additional details to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of @max here is the solution including a selected param and a class.

```rb
select("company", "company_id", Company.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id, { 'data-url-path'=>p.logo_url(:thumb) }] }, { selected: params["company_id"] }, { class: "select-company" })
```

```js
$('#company_company_id').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  var data = e.params.data;
  var src = $('#company_company_id select option[value="' + data.id + '"]').data('url-path');
  $(".my_img").attr("src", src);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select("company", "company_id") do
  Company.all.each do |c|
    content_tag(:option, c.name, value: c.id, data: { src: c.logo_url(:thumb) })
  end
end
```

By passing a block to select you can customize the generation of the option elements and attach a data attribute to the elements.

You can then simply read the data attribute in your event handler:

```
$('#select-company').on('select2:select', function (e) { 
  var src = $(e.params.data.element).data('src');
  $(".my_img").attr("src", src);
});
```

None of this really requires the use of `js.erb` templates.

Comment: I have never actually used select2 so YMMV. I based the JS off https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261209/get-custom-data-attribute-in-select2-with-select